# how to create a new window in ajax in extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4

I know there are othe questions like mine but, the details are important in my case and the details of this question are different from the one in the question already made. however the problem is that I'm trying to build a new window with extjs, starting from a grid already done. This new window should contain a grid with al the references to the element selected of the previous grid.
So this is my solution, I placed an ajax call inside the first grid. I made a column to contain the image to be cliccked to get to the second grid. But it is not working. When i click on the image it doesn't show nothing?

Am I wrong doing the ajax call?Am i wrong passing the json to the page for the store of the grid that should be in the new window? Any idea?
This is the code of my grids:

```
 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: store1,
    stateful: true,
    collapsible: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    stateId: 'stateGrid',
    columns: [
        {
            text     : 'id',
            flex     : 1,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
            text     : 'buyer_member_id',
            width    : 75,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'buyer_member_id'
        },
        {
            text     : 'Client Name',
            width    : 200,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        },
        {
            xtype : 'actioncolumn',
            width : '5%',
            sortable : false,
            items : [{
                icon : '../static/accept.gif',
                tooltip : 'See Admants',
                handler : function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){
                    var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    buyer_member_id = grid.getSelectionModel.getSelection()[1]
                    Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                    };
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method : "GET",     
                        url: '/mygrid/',
                        params:{
                                buyer_member_id: buyer_member_id,
                        },
                        success : function(response) {
                            var obj = response;
                            try {
                                obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            } catch (error) {}
                            if (obj) {
                                Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                                title: 'Hello',
                                height: 200,
                                width: 400,
                                layout: 'fit',
                                items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
                                xtype: 'grid',
                                border: false,
                                columns: [
                                        {
                                            text     : 'id',
                                            flex     : 1,
                                            sortable : true,
                                            dataIndex: 'id'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text     : 'name',
                                            width    : 300,
                                            sortable : true,
                                            dataIndex: 'name'
                                        }],                 // One header just for show. There's no data,
                                store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                                    // store configs
                                    storeId: 'myStore',
                                    proxy: {
                                        type: 'ajax',
                                        url: '/admants/',
                                        reader: {
                                            type: 'json',
                                        }
                                    },})

                                }}).show();
                            } else {
                            alert("Invalid response")
                            }
                        },
                        failure : function(response) {
                            alert("Data request failed");
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }]
        }
    ],
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? What points does the code hit?

Comment: The problem was at first this line: ` buyer_member_id = grid.getSelectionModel.getSelection()[1]` but i found the righ answer to this first problema and about how to create the windows, i still have a problem but not one mentioned in the question. I'm pasting the cose in an answer. Agnese

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code that follows opens a new window and reads the data for the ajax call. STil the "store" is not working but i will post a new question specifically for it.

```
{
            xtype : 'actioncolumn',
            width : '5%',
            sortable : false,
            items : [{
                icon : '../static/accept.gif',
                tooltip : 'See Admants',
                handler : function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){
                    var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                    //buyer_member_id = grid.getSelectionModel.getSelection()[1]
                     var row = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                     var buyer_member_id = row.data.buyer_member_id;
                    Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                    };
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        method : "GET",     
                        url: '/admants/?buyer_member_id='+ buyer_member_id,
                        success : function(response) {
                            var obj = response;
                            try {
                                obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            } catch (error) {}
                            if (obj) {
                                Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                                title: 'Hello',
                                height: 200,
                                width: 400,
                                layout: 'fit',
                                items: {  // Let's put an empty grid in just to illustrate fit layout
                                xtype: 'grid',
                                border: false,
                                columns: [
                                        {
                                            text     : 'id',
                                            flex     : 1,
                                            sortable : true,
                                            dataIndex: 'id'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text     : 'name',
                                            width    : 300,
                                            sortable : true,
                                            dataIndex: 'name'
                                        }],                 // One header just for show. There's no data,
                                store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                                    // store configs
                                    storeId: 'myStore',
                                    proxy: {
                                        type: 'ajax',
                                        url: '/admants/',
                                        reader: {
                                            type: 'json',
                                        }
                                    },})

                                }}).show();
                            } else {
                            alert("Invalid response")
                            }
                        },
                        failure : function(response) {
                            alert("Data request failed");
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }]
        }
    ],
```